# Why is r = theta a straight line on the Cartesian plane?

Tags: polar-coordinates

Note: First time posting on math.stackexchange, so please tell me if I am violating standards...

I am having trouble thinking about how to graph $r=\theta$ on the X-Y coordinate plane. I understand the polar representation of a spiral. Is there a more intuitive approach than changing the equation into rectangular form, and plugging in?

Comment: Why does your title say "straight line"? Polar eq $r=\theta$ denotes a spiral.

Comment: Do you mean (for your title) "Why is $r = \theta$ *not* a straight line on the Cartesian plane?  Because it isn't (as @Deepak points out).